# Don't Post ASP.NET fields __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT and __VIEWSTATE

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, viewstate

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to not post the ASP.Net fields `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTARGUMENT` and `__VIEWSTATE`.

I am posting data to an external page which is not in ASP.NET, so it doesn't need those fields.

I have tried to disable the fields in my Page, but they are still submitted in the POST request (they only are empty).

Do I have to modify programmatically the POST content? Or can I set this in a config file?

Thanks !

Comment: try disabling the VIEWSTATE in your aspx

Comment: Disabling VIEWSTATE in aspx will NOT remove it from the POST content. I have tried in aspx, on the `OnLoad`, in the web.config but none of these solutions is able to prevent these fields from being posted to the page.

Comment: Simplest way is to not use webforms, but stick with MVC. There are of course some ways to filter out these arguments, but... I'd say it's too complicated for its purpose. If you really want to use webforms, just ignore this "feature". Sending blank values is still faster than some dandy hack that you would have to develop to overcome this. It's built in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to prevent these ASP.Net fields to be posted is to remove the fields in the DOM with javascript.

As they are hidden fields automatically included in the form, by removing them after the document loaded, they are not posted anymore.